# Почему не рекомендуется писать строчки кода длиннее 80 символов?

Tags: code-style

Недавно решил ознакомиться с распространёнными стандартами форматирования кода, и первой под руку попалась [Oracle Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html), все рекомендации из которой выглядят всесьма логично. Кроме одной:

> Avoid lines longer than 80 characters,
> since they're not handled well by many
> terminals and tools.

Казалось бы, век алфавитно-цифровых мониторов с разрешением 25 * 80 символов давно сменился веком широкоформатных дисплеев. И почему бы теперь не увеличить границу до **приемлемых** масштабов, сохранив несчастные строчки нераздробленными?

**Есть ли у рекомендации другие причины оставаться актуальной, или её лучше игнорировать?**

Comment: Приемлемых - это сколько? Предложите конкретное число.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Эта рекомендация работает при печати исходников на бумагу. Для печати исходников используется моноширинный шрифт типа Courier. Обычно все IDE исторически настроены при печати на бумагу на определенный размер шрифта под те самые 80 символов.

Если вы не намерены постоянно печатать исходники и потом изучать это в метро по пути домой или дома в заведении МЖ - то можно забыть об этом.

Я лично уже давно плюю на ширину 80.

Answer (score 11):

Да, есть актуальные причины.

Во-первых трехсторонний мерж кода, например в kdiff3. При максимальной длине строки в 80 символов, код едва помещается на экран.
[image: 3-way merge in kdiff3]

Кроме мержа есть еще и side-by-side diff, например при просмотре pull-request в браузере, если сбоку от диффа также показывается дерево файлов - то 90-100 символов в строке это наверное максимум при котором весь код виден на экране.

Во-вторых многие работают одновременно с несколькими файлами в IDE, или с несколькими окнами терминала. Сейчас горизонтально расположенные мониторы имеют ширину 1920 пикселов - это как раз 3 столбца примерно по 80 символов. Либо два столбца по 100 символов, и дерево файлов в IDE.

Comment: Точно. 2 фрейма emacs-а с кодом и окно терминала сбоку от них закрывают почти весь экран.

Answer (score 4):

Банально не удобно читать.

```
NSInvocationOperation *op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget: self selector: @selector(createAsyncConnectonInBackgroundWithParameters:) object: dictionary];
```

Comment: На самом деле без принудительных переносов это выглядело бы хуже.

Comment: Только обычно параметры не имеют названий. По крайней мере, такое я видел только в Objective-C. А методы с шестью и более параметрами чаще всего бывают результатом некрасивой архитектуры.

Comment: @Angry 6 и более это уже слишком, разумеется. Названия да, тоже, конечно, свое место занимают.

Answer (score 3):

В современном мире ограничение длины строк направленно прежде всего на упрощение выражений в этих самых строках. То же ограничение в 80 или 120 символов заставляет разносить сложную логику или выражения по функциям, а также давать функциям и объектам более короткие, емкие и выразительные имена.

Answer (score 0):

думаю, что сегодня можно это требование вполне игнорировать.

но тем не менее, если вашим кодом будут пользоваться, стоит сделать для себя какое-то разумное ограничение, зная, что бывают экраны меньше вашего.

P.S. но длинные строки - это всё-таки дурной тон, так как читать их сложнее, так что советую часто не использовать.

Comment: к тому же не всегда весь экран занят под редактор кода, часто всякие обозреватели проектов, окна свойств и прочего занимают добрую часть слева или справа

Comment: Второй монитор в помощь!

Comment: не поможет, если в среде разработки всё это хозяйство в одном окне.
да и дешевле писать строки покороче;)

Comment: Ну почему же не помогает - панели обозревателей, отладчика, свойств и проч. легко двигаются на второй экран - экран кода расширяется и все.

Comment: ну может, если мониторы одного размера, у меня второй сильно меньше и одно окно удобно на оба монитора не растянешь.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, других причин нет. Это сделано только для отсутствия горизонтальных прокруток в исходном коде. Этот Convention, по-моему, вообще не обновляется.